# Losing value of variable

Tags: java, sql

I'm doing a Login form using SQL Server and using three layer architecture, I debugged the project and basically it works like this: I put the user and password in the jframe, the user and pass are sent to the BL method and then to DA, when I put the user and pass correctly the Query is executed and "resultado" value is 1, then it goes back to the GUI but when its validated "getResultado" the value of "resultado" is 0, therefore I can't login.

This is my GUI method:

```
u.validarLogin(jtxtUsuario.getText(), String.valueOf(jpsfContrasenia.getPassword()));
    if (admin.getResultado() == 1) {
        new jfrmInterno().setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre de usuario ingresado no coincide con ninguna cuenta", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        jtxtUsuario.setText("");
        jpsfContrasenia.setText("");
    }
}
```

This is my BL method:

```
 public void validarLogin(String user, String pass) {
        if (user != null && pass != null) {
            admin.setUsuario(user, pass);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Incorrecto");
        }
    }
```

This is my DA method:

```
public int setUsuario(String user, String pass) {
    this.getConexion();
    String usuario = user;
    String password = pass;
    try {
        Statement ejecutor = cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = ejecutor.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Login] where NombreUsuario = '" + usuario + "' AND Contrasenia= '" + password + "'");
        if (rs.next()) {
            resultado = 1;
        } else {
            resultado = 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return resultado;
}

public int getResultado() {
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: are you calling getResultado on the same object you called setUsuario on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify the code, do this;

1. Add a return type to your BL method

```
public int validarLogin(String user, String pass) {
        int resultado = 0;
        if (user != null && pass != null) {
            resultado = admin.setUsuario(user, pass);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Incorrecto");
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

2. Then change your GUI method to this;

```
int resultado = u.validarLogin(jtxtUsuario.getText(), String.valueOf(jpsfContrasenia.getPassword()));
    if (resultado == 1) {
        new jfrmInterno().setVisible(true);
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El nombre de usuario ingresado no coincide con ninguna cuenta", "", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        jtxtUsuario.setText("");
        jpsfContrasenia.setText("");
    }
}
```

This should definitely work as now you are returning the result as a variable every time validation BL method is being called.

Forgive me in case of any typos.